# CronJob for mysqldump then delete files and then copy the files and then delete again

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, cron, backup

I need a cronjob where I need 4 following functions.

- Step1: mysqldump

> mysqldump -h HOSTNAME -uroot -proot --all-databases >
> backup/dump_$(date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S").sql

- Step2: delete sqldump files when they are older than 14 days

> find /usr/bin/find /backup/*.sql -mtime +14 -delete;

- Step3: push this all .sql mysqldump files which left after step 2 on another server.
- Step4: like Step2 but this time on the server where I pushed the .sql files.

I need it like this because, my cronjob is running in Kubernetes Cluster.
The Server with the database is not in the Kubernetes Cluster and the Server where I need to push the .sql files is not in Kubernetes Cluster too. I already rollout the cronjob in Kubernetes but I need the commands to do what I want.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you struggling with? I would suggest changing your current mysqldump command to [compress the output](https://mysqldump.guru/how-to-compress-mysqldump-backup.html) before storing and pushing to other locations. Perhaps `mysqldump -h HOSTNAME -uroot -proot --all-databases | gzip -9 > backup/dump_$(date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S").sql.gz`. Add rsync command for syncing to other server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to use a script to do this.  Please make an effort and then post the script here.  Or you can look at my script [on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278854/weekly-mysql-database-backup) and modify to suit.    Or for a more advanced version (incorporating the suggestions is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280319/how-to-get-an-overall-error-status-for-the-mysql-backup-operation).  In the mean time, I am voting to close it.

Comment: thanks, I will check it out and give a feedback.